# Bash script delete all files except a selection of files

Tags: bash

I have My bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euxo pipefail
I_PATH=$(pwd)

shopt -s extglob 

for BASE in Adenina Citocina Guanina Timina
do
    cd ${BASE}
    rm !(*.psf|*.fdf|siesta|*.log)
    cd ${I_PATH}
done
```

I want it to delete all files except for the excluded files. The problem is that bash executes the command as follows

```
rm '!(*.psf|*.fdf|siesta|*.log)'
```

Then the script fails with

```
rm: cannot remove '!(*.psf|*.fdf|siesta|*.log)': No such file or directory
```

How can I prevent that the script to add '  ' to the command?

Comment: These `'` are added only in the message.  If you have not put them in the command, they are no added before execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **find** command

```
for BASE in Adenina Citocina Guanina Timina
do
  find ${BASE} -type f ! -name "*.psf" ! -name "*.fdf" ! -name "siesta" ! -name"*.log" -delete
done
```

Comment: With `find Adenina Citocina ... -type ...` you don't need the loop. Depending on OP's requirements you may want to add `-maxdepth 1`.

Comment: Why?
directory name could be "siesta" or "mydir.log/"

Comment: If one of the excluded names is a directory, (some of) its contents may be deleted because `-delete` implies `-depth`. This is why I suggested `-maxdepth`. But since OP accepted this answer, it seems all of the excluded names were files.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there are no matches for your glob, resulting in the glob to be treated as a literal string. Enable nullglob to expand to nothing in case there are no matches

`rm` without any arguments may print an error, therefore we also use `rm -f`.

By the way: Globs work with brace expansions. You don't need the loop or `cd`.

```
shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s extglob
rm -f {Adenina,Citocina,Guanina,Timina}/!(*.psf|*.fdf|siesta|*.log)
```

Or `{Aden,Citoc,Guan,Tim}ina/...` if you want to shave off some bytes :)